# How to control when to show the delete's link in the view according to user 's identity

Tags: drupal, view, controls

I created a view with many fields of one node type, one of the fields is the delete link, but I just want to show the delete link only to the author of this node, those who are not author should not see the delete link

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have permissions (admin/user/permissions) set up so that only the author of the node can delete it, Views will automatically recognize that and hide the delete link for users without permission to delete the node.

In short:  Make sure your permissions are set correctly at admin/user/permissions